# Changing JLabel Foreground for multiple labels

Tags: java, arrays, swing, colors, jlabel

I am kind of stuck trying to change the foreground colour for some JLabels I have.

I got 42 different items I can activate in my app. Each item has it's own JLabel. I made a boolean array to check if the item is activated or not and another String array to check for the items place in my list.

Now the problem is that each item has it's own JLabel that i want to change the colour of. The JLabels are called char0, char1, ... , char41. I tried to use the place number to get to a specific label but sadly that won't work, so I implemented an array for my labels.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;    
JLabel[] label = setLabel();    
    public JLabel[] setLabel(){
        JLabel[] labels = {char0,char1,...,char41};
        return labels;
    }
```

So basically I got an array of the JLabel type which should hold my 42 labels. Now to get them back and change the colour this is what I tried:

```
getLabel(place).setForeground(Color.green);
    public JLabel getLabel(int place){
        return label[place];
    }
```

Sadly I get this exception:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at werwolf.GUI.setCharacter(GUI.java:1068)
at werwolf.GUI.jButton1MouseClicked(GUI.java:1040)
at werwolf.GUI.access$100(GUI.java:17)
at werwolf.GUI$2.mouseClicked(GUI.java:199)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please only show real code, not kind-of sort-of code. This will help us immensely. Best if you could create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The exception is not caused by the code you posted in your question. Please add that code (e. g. `GUI.setCharacter`, the accessed fields and their initialization).

Comment: I just posted almost all of the code to pastie, since I used the JFrame designer netbeans offers to add the frames I have no idea how they 'actually' work. I deleted most of the JLabel initializations since I thought 4 out of the 42 should be enough: http://pastie.org/9849108

Comment: Your "pastie" code doesn't compile or run

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem maybe here is my mcve of an implementation that changes label colors. You need to set the label opaque true.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;    
public class Main
{
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("labelframe");
    Container contents = myframe.getContentPane();
    JLabel[] label = setLabel();  
    JButton change = new JButton("change color");
    public Main()
    {
        contents.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,9));
        for(JLabel thislabel : label)
        {
            thislabel.setEnabled(true);
            thislabel.setOpaque(true);
            contents.add(thislabel);            
        }
        change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               changeLabelColor();
            }
        });     
        contents.add(change);
        myframe.setVisible(true);
        myframe.pack();
    }
     private void changeLabelColor()
     {
         for(JLabel thislabel : label)
         {

             thislabel.setBackground(Color.red);
             thislabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
         }
     }
    public JLabel[] setLabel()
    {
        JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[42];
        for(int x = 0; x < labels.length; x++)
        {
            labels[x] = new JLabel("char" + x);
        }
        return labels;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Main();
    }
```